# How do I delete_many filtering by two conditions?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm using pymongo to try and `delete_many` records where it matches two conditions but it's not deleting any records:

```
db.hashes.delete_many(
  {"highlights": {"$exists": "false"}}, {"last_pulled": {"$lte": purgeDate}} ## This works in mongosh as expected, but not pymongo.
)
```

i've tried to put the two conditions in an `$and` array but that didn't work either:

```
db.hashes.delete_many(
  {"$and": [{"highlights": {"$exists": "false"}}, {"last_pulled": {"$lte": purgeDate}}]}
)
```

When I filter by just the one `purgeDate` condition it does delete records as expected:

```
db.domains.delete_many({"last_pulled": {"$lte": purgeDate}})
```

but I need both conditions to filter by.

p.s. this is how I'm setting purgeDate:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

N_DAYS_AGO = 90
purgeDate = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=N_DAYS_AGO)
```

Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: is `purgeDate` a date? is `last_pulled` an ISODate? Maybe one of them is a string...

Comment: Can you post the result of `print(purgeDate)`?

Comment: purgeDate is  `datetime.now() - timedelta(days=90)` and prints as `2022-11-04 14:08:30.203886`. `last_pulled` is an ISODate

Comment: Does this do what you want: `db.hashes.delete_many({"highlights": {"$exists": "false"}, "last_pulled": {"$lte": purgeDate}})`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs unfortunately it doesn't. none of the records are deleting. :(

Comment: What is the output of `db.hashes.count_documents({"highlights": {"$exists": False}, "last_pulled": {"$lte": purgeDate}})`?  I think you may want `False` rather than `"false".

Comment: That gives me 0. When I do count for just the highlights filter it gives me 19, and then just for the date filter it gives me 21158.

Comment: Oh I think the issue was `False` rather than "false"!!!! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a subtle misplacement of braces, combined with the wrong boolean expression. The sytntax you want is:

```
db.hashes.delete_many(
  {"highlights": {"$exists": False}, "last_pulled": {"$lte": purgeDate}}
)
```

Comment: I just realised this was exactly as posted in the comments; I spotted it earlier but couldn't post at the time. Hope it's all working now. For info the reason the mongo shell and pymongo will sometimes give different results is that the pymongo methods will take different parameters; in your instance you were passing `{"last_pulled": {"$lte": purgeDate}}` to the collation parameter. https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.delete_one